# Failed to register user user1.Failed to get Affiliation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

```
PS C:\Users\07\OneDrive\Desktop\Final Try\fabcar-blockchain-sample\web-app\server> node registerUser.js
Wallet path: C:\Users\07\OneDrive\Desktop\Final Try\fabcar-blockchain-sample\web-app\server\wallet
Failed to register user user1: Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":0,"message":"Registration of 'user1' failed in affiliation validation: Failed getting affiliation 'org1.department1': : scode: 404, code: 63, msg: Failed to get Affiliation: sql: no rows in result set"}]]
```

> **Failed to register user user1.Failed to get Affiliation.Here, in this I'm following the basic Hyperledger faberic Fabcar tutorial. But I'm geting error as failed to Register user user1.msg: Failed to get Affiliation: sql: no rows in result set". The tutorial which I'm following is, https://github.com/IBM/fabcar-blockchain-sample. **

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://github.com/IBM/fabcar-blockchain-sample/blob/master/web-app/server/registerUser.js#L56

If you change

```
const secret = await ca.register({ affiliation: 'org1.department1', enrollmentID: userName, role: 'client' }, adminIdentity);
```

to

```
const secret = await ca.register({ enrollmentID: userName, role: 'client' }, adminIdentity);
```

then things should work.  I think the demo was created for an older version where we used to have built-in affiliations.

Comment: Hi @Gari Singh sir... Thanks a loads it worked for me. Sir, as well as please help me in running the project... my next error is here in "npm start" command of the server. Please Sir. Here is my next question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593377/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command