# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

```
 npm start

> server@1.0.0 start C:\Users\07\OneDrive\Desktop\Final Try\fabcar-blockchain-sample\web-app\server
> ./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\07\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-04T13_24_08_021Z-debug.log
```

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,.Here, in this I'm following the basic Hyperledger faberic Fabcar tutorial. But I'm geting error as "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command". The tutorial which I'm following is, https://github.com/IBM/fabcar-blockchain-sample.

Comment: Doesn't look like that sample is windows friendly. Suggest you try using linux instead

Answer (score 1):

Edit [package.json](https://github.com/IBM/fabcar-blockchain-sample/blob/master/web-app/server/package.json#L7) and remove the `./`.

change

```
"start": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js"
```

to

```
"start": "nodemon src/app.js"
```

Alternatively, you can try

`npm install -g nodemon`

and change the `start` command to

```
"start": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

change the folder name "Final Try" to "final-try" and try again.. it'll work
(folder name has space in between)